# using jQuery Glow in Intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I want to use [this jquery glow plugin](https://github.com/nakajima/jquery-glow) in my page. [(DEMO)](http://nakajima.github.com/jquery-glow/)

and I want my text blinks every 4 second. I write this code but it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.white').addGlow({ textColor: 'white', haloColor: '#aaa', radius: 100 });
        setInterval(function () {
            $('.white').mouseenter();
            setTimeout(function () { }, 2000);
            $('.white').mouseleave();
        }, 2000);
    });
```

how I can do this?

thanks

Comment: you want it to start blink on hover, right?

Comment: no I want it starts automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I'm no fan of faking an effect if the plugin does not provide an api for it (meaning the lack of possibility to trigger the glow in the jquery-glow plugin), here is a possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/3LCdA/

```
(function loop() {
  $('.green').mouseover();
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.green').mouseout();
    setTimeout(loop, 2000);
  }, 2000);
}());
```

or with parameters:

http://jsfiddle.net/3LCdA/1/

```
(function loop(el, delay) {
  el.mouseover();
  setTimeout(function () {
    el.mouseout();
    setTimeout(function () {
      loop(el, delay);
    }, delay);
  }, delay);
}($('.green'), 2000));
```